# Find function is only finding part of value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro in VBA which copies values from one worksheet to another using the find function.

My workbook calculates certain variables depending on the span length of a bridge. The span length changes iteratively and I have named the variable "SpanLength". Each time the span length changes the macro copies the maximum values and pastes them to worksheet "MAXIMUM" (shown in the image attached). In MAXIMUM I have named all the top row of span lengths (1, 1.2, 1,4 etc.) "FindSpanLength". The macro then *finds* the appropriate span length here and paste  the maximum values next to it. This macro works except for with span lengths 2, 4, 6 and 8 where instead of finding these span lengths in MAXIMUM, it finds span lengths 1,2, 1.4, 1.6 and 1.8 and copies the results there.

[image: x]

I have tried using Lookat:=xlWhole but this exacerbates the problem. Does anyone have any other solutions?

[image: xlWhole]

```
 Private Sub Max()

    ' Chooses correct column: Find the span length column and name this outputcolumn
    Dim spanlengthcell As Range, outputcolumn As Integer
    Set spanlengthcell = Range("FindSpanLength").Find(Range("SpanLength").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not spanlengthcell Is Nothing Then
     outputcolumn = spanlengthcell.Column
    End If

' Chooses correct row: If the cell to the left of spanlengthcell is empty then this is the first row of output otherwise find next empty cell down
If MAXIMUM.Cells(4, outputcolumn + 1).Value = "" Then
    outputrow = 4
ElseIf MAXIMUM.Cells(5, outputcolumn + 1).Value = "" Then
    outputrow = 5
Else
    outputrow = MAXIMUM.Cells(4, outputcolumn + 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
End If

' Copy starting point, max bending moment and max shear from calculate to output
MAXIMUM.Cells(outputrow, outputcolumn + 1).Value = Sheets("Calculate").Range("StartPoint").Value
MAXIMUM.Cells(outputrow, outputcolumn + 2).Value = Sheets("Calculate").Range("[enter image description here][1]MaxBM").Value
MAXIMUM.Cells(outputrow, outputcolumn + 3).Value = Sheets("Calculate").Range("MaxSF").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: You could try `match` on the range to get the row/column?

Comment: What is the problem with `xlWhole`? I mean, what happens when you use it.

Comment: I've shown what happens when using xlWhole in image 2 in the description. Essentially for all integer span lengths, the values are just pasted in the first 3 columns.

Comment: On the xwhole image you attached i can't find de 1.2, 1.6 on the column A, is it supposed to find the values you are putting in the yellow cells on the Column A?